# a hard problem for me about measurable functions and cantor set and lusin theory

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Construct a function $f : [0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ as follows. Let $\{I_n\}$ be an
enumeration of the open intervals in [0, 1] having rational endpoints.
For each $n \in \mathbb N$, let $K_n \subset I_n$ be a Cantor set of positive Lebesgue measure such that the sequence $\{K_n\}$ is pairwise disjoint and
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty λ(K_n ) = 1$. Define $f_n$ on $K_n $ to be continuous on $K_n $, nondecreasing, and such that $f_n (K_n ) = [0, 1]$. Let

$f(n) =
\begin{cases}
f_n (x),  & \text{if  $$x$ \in k_n$} \\
0, & \text{if $x$ $\in [0,1]$ \ $\cup_{n=0}^\infty k_n$}
\end{cases}$

(a) Show that f is Lebesgue measurable.

(b) Show that f (I) = [0, 1] for every open interval $I \subset [0, 1]$.

(c) Using the sets $K_n $, find continuous functions on [0, 1] that approximate f in the Lusin sense.

i read real analysis Bruckner by myself. i don't solve this problem. it is valuable for me to be solved it.
thank you so much

Comment: I know what is the ternary [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set). What do you call "**A** Cantor set"?

Comment: yes A cantor set

Comment: What do you call "A Cantor set"?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Isn't it usually a closed set with all its points on the boundary ? This definition seems fine to answer the question - but I don't know if it was the one given.